# Unable to successfully start Chrome using Selenium on GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Debian-based Google Compute Engine to run my Selenium scripts, but I cannot for the life of me run any scripts interfacing with Chrome. I have tried installing both Chrome and Chromium - and all dependencies - without getting any further. It still fails

**The webdriverio script: script.js**

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } };
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);
client
    .init()
    .then(()=> {
        console.log('init ok')
    },
    (err)=> {
        console.log('init failed', err)
    })
    .url('https://duckduckgo.com/')
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title is: ' + title);
    })
    .end();
```

**Full output from `node script.js`**

This is basically a subset of the error from the Selenium process

```
init failed { Error
  message: 'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c15
31b57),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)\nCommand duration or timeout: 60.05 s
econds\nBuild info: version: \'3.4.0\', revision: \'unknown\', time: \'unknown\'\nSystem info: host: \'dev-ACME-no\', ip: \'10.132.0.2\', os.name: 
\'Linux\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'3.16.0-4-amd64\', java.version: \'1.8.0_121\'\nDriver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver',
  type: 'RuntimeError',
  seleniumStack: 
   { status: 13,
     type: 'UnknownError',
     message: 'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.',
     orgStatusMessage: 'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291
d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)\nCommand duration or time
out: 60.05 seconds\nBuild info: version: \'3.4.0\', revision: \'unknown\', time: \'unknown\'\nSystem info: host: \'dev-ACME-no\', ip: \'10.132.0.2\
', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'3.16.0-4-amd64\', java.version: \'1.8.0_121\'\nDriver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver' 
} }
```

**The selenium process**

```
13:26:19.237 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown'
13:26:19.237 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-06-21 13:26:19.256:INFO::main: Logging initialized @248ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
13:26:19.306 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the c
urrent platform LINUX
13:26:19.306 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
13:26:19.306 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
13:26:19.307 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
13:26:19.307 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
13:26:19.307 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
13:26:19.308 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform LINUX
2017-06-21 13:26:19.347:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.3.v20170317
2017-06-21 13:26:19.384:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@55f3ddb1{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-06-21 13:26:19.400:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1794d431{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-06-21 13:26:19.400:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @393ms
13:26:19.400 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
13:26:19.685 INFO - SessionCleaner initialized with insideBrowserTimeout 0 and clientGoneTimeout 1800000 polling every 180000
Selenium started
13:26:24.408 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.L
oggingPreferences@71d24c0f, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.6.2, url=ht
tp://webdriver.io}}]])
13:26:24.435 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging
.LoggingPreferences@71d24c0f, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.6.2, url=
http://webdriver.io}}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57) on port 19256
Only local connections are allowed.
13:27:24.920 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'dev-ACME-no', ip: '10.132.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:131)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:36)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:190)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:184)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:150)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:543)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1228)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1130)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:112)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:122)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.ExecutingExecutionStrategy.invoke(ExecutingExecutionStrategy.java:58)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:201)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:133)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'dev-ACME-no', ip: '10.132.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:110)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:96)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:209)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:102)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.05 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'dev-ACME-no', ip: '10.132.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
        ... 14 more
13:27:24.924 WARN - Exception: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.05 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'dev-ACME-no', ip: '10.132.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to enlightenment started when trying to narrow the problem down.

At least these parts must be working for the scripts to run:

1. Selenium and friends (`webdriverio`, ChromeDriver, etc)
2. Chrome and dependencies must be installed
3. Xvfb must work
4. Chrome must run on Xvfb
5. Chrome must somehow run on Xvfb when triggered through Selenium

To work through it:
The `selenium-standalone start` seemed to work without errors, so 1 was OK. 2, 3 and 4 seemed to work as `xvfb-run google-chrome  --disable-gpu` worked fine. Not sure about 5 ...

One pointer that pointed in the direction of the combo of Chrome+Selenium did not work was one line in the output:

```
Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

We know that Chrome works if X is in place. We know that Chrome fails if X is not in place.

Well to get 5 running I needed to inject Xvfb into the mix somehow, which left me two options. Either wrap the node process or the selenium process. The first did not work, but the second did!

In one terminal:

```
xvfb-run selenium-standalone start
```

In the second terminal:

```
node /tmp/script.js
```

And finally I got the right response

```
init ok
Title is: DuckDuckGo
```

**Some additional debugging help on setting this up**

It pays to look through the exception stack traces of Selenium when trying to debug what is wrong.

You can be sure you are missing Chrome, or it is not installed, when you get this

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

If you don't have the right version of Chrome for Chromedriver, for instance if you only installed Chromium (my case!), you will see this error:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Ensure that `google-chrome-stable` is in the `$PATH` and that you can execute it successfully on a headless system.

**Further tips on setup**
Check out [this automated setup](https://github.com/garywu/google-compute-engine-selenium/blob/master/install.sh). Lots of nice pointers.